# Asymmetry of kernel pairs

Tags: category-theory

The kernel pair of an arrow is defined as the pullback of $A\overset{f}{\rightarrow} B\overset{f}{\leftarrow} A$. This definitions seems to be very symmetric, and yet the pullback $(P,\alpha,\beta)$ satisfies $\alpha=\beta$ if and only if $f$ is a monomorphism. I just noticed that I find this strange, since both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the pullback of $f$ along itself.

Can anybody explain what's going on? Why would $\alpha$ and $\beta$ generally differ? The proof that they're equal iff $f$ is a mono is clear to me, it just doesn't settle with the symmetry of the definition..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of the case when $B$ is the terminal object and $f$ is the unique map $A\to B$. Then the pullback $P$ is just the product $A\times A$, and the maps $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the projections on the two components. Clearly these are different!

But in general ($B$ isn't necessarily terminal now) there's a natural automorphism $\sigma:P\to P$ which "swaps" $\alpha$ and $\beta$, in the sense that $\alpha\circ \sigma = \beta$ and $\beta\circ \sigma = \alpha$. You obtain $\sigma$ from the universal property of the pullback by mapping $P$ to the first copy of $A$ by $\beta$ and to the second copy of $A$ by $\alpha$. In the case of the cartesian product of sets, this is the map $(x,y)\mapsto (y,x)$. I would view this is a manifestation of the symmetry that you're looking for: $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not equal, but they're isomorphic in the category of arrows to $A$.

*Edit:* You've asked in the comments how to see that $\sigma$ is an isomorphism. Well, we have $\alpha\circ \sigma\circ \sigma = \beta\circ \sigma = \alpha$ and $\beta\circ \sigma\circ \sigma = \alpha \circ \sigma = \beta$. But the universal property of the pullback tells us that $\text{id}_P$ is the unique map $f\colon P\to P$ such that $\alpha \circ f = \alpha$ and $\beta\circ f = \beta$. Hence $\sigma\circ \sigma = \text{id}_P$, and $\sigma$ is self-inverse.

Comment: Sorry, but why are the projections to the components different? That also seems counterintuitive to me. Could you explain your example in more detail? Also, it seems intuitive that this symmetry arrow $\sigma$ should be an isomorphism. Is this true? Thanks!

Comment: Let's think about the category of sets. Let $A$ be any set. Then we have the maps $\alpha\colon A\times A \to A$ given by $(x,y)\mapsto x$ and $\beta\colon A\times A \to A$ given by $(x,y)\mapsto y$. These are different maps (as long as $A$ has $\geq 2$ elements). Yes?

Comment: Oh, haha, silly of me. Now just the bit about $\sigma$..

Comment: Yes, $\sigma$ is an isomorphism. An automorphism is an isomorphism from an object to itself.

Comment: Should we delete this thread of comments?

Comment: We can if you want, but they could be useful to some future person.